# Kendo Grid with Polymer Js

Tags: polymer, kendo-grid, polymer-1.0

I am using Kendo Grid in my Polymer App.

```
var grid = $(self.$.mygrid).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: res,
                    type: Object,
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                resizable: true,
                navigatable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                groupable: false,
                sortable: false,
                scrollable: {
                    virtual: true
                },
                columns: self._Column()
            });

_Column: function() {
            var res = this.myArray;
            var columns = [];
            _.each(res, function(obj) {
                if (obj != null && obj != undefined) {
                    switch (obj.field.toLowerCase()) {
                        case '':
                            obj.template = '<div><iron-image src=\".image.jpg\" ></iron-image></div>';
                            break;
                    }
                    columns.push(obj);
                }
            });
```

I will be dynamically adding the kedo templates. How do i write listners for iron-image click.

if i try something like this

```
<iron-image src=\"image.jpg" id="tab"></iron-image>
```

and add listener

```
listeners: {
            'tab.click': '_clickEvent'
        },
```

I am getting below error

**polymer.html:495 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key**

Comment: Why don't you try `on-tap="tab"` on iron-image

Comment: tried already that "tab" function is not invoked in the polyer element's script. But if i decleare the function in global <script></script>. its exectuing. I need that function to be invoked in polyer script

Comment: Can you post the whole code for the element? I think your problem might be syntax-related